# How to add array to $data array CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array, echo

I have some $data that i am transfering to view, ok that is easy

But i want this

```
    $data['promenjive']=array
(
     '1'    => prva,
     '2'    => 'druga',
     '3'    => 'treca',

);
```

And

```
$this->load->view("view_home", $data);
```

My question is how to echo a single value from **$data['promenjive']**

To make something like this

```
<a href="prva">1</a>
```

I dont want to foreach entire array just one element?

Answer (score 2):

In your example `prva` would echoed from within your view template with:

```
<?php echo $promenjive[1];?>
```

To echo `1` from your example you would have to do:

```
<?php echo array_search('druga',$promenjive);?>
```